# $(\frac{1}{d}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]) = d^m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ of degree $m$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $d$ be any positive integer.

> How can I see/prove, that $(\frac{1}{d}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]) = d^m$?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{d}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ are free abelian groups of rank $m$ and so we're taking about $({(\frac{1}{d}\mathbb Z)}^m : \mathbb Z^m)$.